# Weka: Src and Dest differ in # of attributes: using java

Tags: java, machine-learning, weka, svm, libsvm

I am trying to run Support Vector Machine(SVM) classifier using Weka API in my java code. I am getting following error **"Src and Dest differ in # of attributes:"** on line 13. Please guide me how can I resolve this problem and run classifier successfully(THIS IS MY TIME CRITICAL ACADEMIC PROJECT). If possible, kindly mention the solution with example.

**ERROR:**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Src and Dest differ in # of attributes: 22 != 31
    at weka.core.RelationalLocator.copyRelationalValues(RelationalLocator.java:88)
    at weka.filters.Filter.copyValues(Filter.java:359)
    at weka.filters.Filter.push(Filter.java:276)
    at weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Standardize.convertInstance(Standardize.java:260)
    at weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Standardize.input(Standardize.java:142)
    at weka.filters.Filter.useFilter(Filter.java:661)
    at ClassifierJan12Pure.main(ClassifierJan12Pure.java:139)
```

**JAVA CODE:**

```
1.     filteredData = new Instances(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("training.arff")));

2.     filteredData.setClassIndex(0);

3.     Classifier classifier=new SMO();

4.     classifier.buildClassifier(filteredData);

5.     FilteredClassifier filteredClassifier=new FilteredClassifier();
6.     filteredClassifier.setClassifier(classifier);
7.     Filter filter = new StringToWordVector(1000);
8.     filteredClassifier.setFilter(filter);

9.     Instances filteredTests= new Instances(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("testing.arff")));

10.    Standardize sfilter = new Standardize();
11.    sfilter.setInputFormat(filteredData);  // initializing the filter once with training set

12.    Instances newTrain = Filter.useFilter(filteredData, sfilter);  // configures the Filter based on train instances and returns filtered instances

**13.    Instances testsF = Filter.useFilter(filteredTests, sfilter);    // create new test set   ///<<<<<<< Error line.**

14.    Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(filteredData);
15.    eval.evaluateModel(filteredClassifier, filteredTests);

16.    System.out.println(eval.toSummaryString("\nResults\n", false));
```

**training.arff**

```
@relation '_Users_Passionate_Desktop_Training_Text-weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToWordVector-R1-W1000-prune-rate-1.0-N0-stemmerweka.core.stemmers.NullStemmer-M1-tokenizerweka.core.tokenizers.WordTokenizer -delimiters \" \\r\\n\\t.,;:\\\'\\\"()?!\"'

@attribute @@class@@ {dummy,ham,spam}
@attribute about numeric
@attribute and numeric
@attribute be numeric
@attribute construction numeric
@attribute discussion numeric
@attribute me numeric
@attribute much numeric
@attribute np numeric
@attribute of numeric
@attribute reminds numeric
@attribute s numeric
@attribute said numeric
@attribute second numeric
@attribute that numeric
@attribute the numeric
@attribute to numeric
@attribute very numeric
@attribute agree numeric
@attribute auto numeric
@attribute boxes numeric
@attribute credit numeric
@attribute dear numeric
@attribute display numeric
@attribute have numeric
@attribute ll numeric
@attribute nlpeople numeric
@attribute sure numeric
@attribute we numeric
@attribute with numeric
@attribute you numeric

@data
{0 ham,1 1,2 1,3 1,4 1,7 1,8 1,12 1,13 1,15 1,16 1,17 1}
{0 ham,5 1,6 1,8 1,9 1,10 1,11 1,14 1,15 1}
{0 spam,18 1,19 1,22 1,25 1,26 1,27 1,30 1}
{0 spam,20 1,21 1,23 1,24 1,28 1,29 1}
```

**Testing.arff**

```
@relation '_Users_Passionate_Desktop_TestingDiffThanTesting_Text-weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToWordVector-R1-W1000-prune-rate-1.0-N0-stemmerweka.core.stemmers.NullStemmer-M1-tokenizerweka.core.tokenizers.WordTokenizer -delimiters \" \\r\\n\\t.,;:\\\'\\\"()?!\"'

@attribute @@class@@ {dummy,ham,spam}
@attribute brazilian numeric
@attribute do numeric
@attribute in numeric
@attribute indigenous numeric
@attribute languages numeric
@attribute linguists numeric
@attribute on numeric
@attribute prepare numeric
@attribute research numeric
@attribute specialization numeric
@attribute to numeric
@attribute and numeric
@attribute be numeric
@attribute developed numeric
@attribute evaluation numeric
@attribute of numeric
@attribute program numeric
@attribute published numeric
@attribute reanalysis numeric
@attribute the numeric
@attribute will numeric

@data
{0 ham,1 1,3 1,4 1,5 1,10 1}
{0 ham,2 1,4 1,6 1,7 1,8 1,9 1,11 1}
{0 spam,12 1,15 1,16 1,18 1,19 1}
{0 spam,5 1,13 1,14 1,17 1,20 1,21 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks James & Michael, I am able to resolve problem of "Src and Dest differ in # of attributes:".

**Step 1:** 
Running TextDirectoryLoader for training and testing folders.

```
java weka.core.converters.TextDirectoryLoader -dir Testing_Text > testing.arff
```

**Step 2:**
Following command actually giving me same number of attributes in training.arff & testing.arff files(http://weka.wikispaces.com/Batch+filtering). I was making mistake to run StringToWordVector command separately which was giving me different number of attributes in training.arff and testing.arff files.

```
java weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToWordVector -b -i training.arff -o train_std.arff -r testing.arff -s test_std.arff
```

**Now I am facing another problem:**

Even though, I am giving setClassIndex in line 3 but still it is showing error message "Class is not set!".

**Error**:

```
weka.core.UnassignedClassException: Class is not set!
weka.core.UnassignedClassException: Class is not set!
    at weka.core.Instance.setClassMissing(Instance.java:544)
    at weka.classifiers.Evaluation.evaluateModelOnceAndRecordPrediction(Evaluation.java:1439)
    at weka.classifiers.Evaluation.evaluateModel(Evaluation.java:1412)
    at ClassifierJan12Pure.main(ClassifierJan12Pure.java:94)
```

**Jave Code:**

```
1.        filteredData = new Instances(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/Passionate/Desktop/train_std.arff")));     

2.         Instances filteredTests= new Instances(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/Passionate/Desktop/test_std.arff")));

3.         filteredData.setClassIndex(filteredData.attribute("@@class@@").index());

4.         Classifier classifier=new SMO();

5.         classifier.buildClassifier(filteredData);

6.         FilteredClassifier filteredClassifier=new FilteredClassifier();
7.         filteredClassifier.setClassifier(classifier);

8.         Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(filteredData);
9.         eval.evaluateModel(filteredClassifier, filteredTests); **// Error line.**

10.        System.out.println(eval.toSummaryString("\nResults\n======\n", false));
```

**train_std.arff file:**

```
@relation '_Users_Passionate_Desktop_Training_Text-weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToWordVector-R1-W1000-prune-rate-1.0-N0-stemmerweka.core.stemmers.NullStemmer-M1-tokenizerweka.core.tokenizers.WordTokenizer -delimiters \" \\r\\n\\t.,;:\\\'\\\"()?!\"'

@attribute @@class@@ {dummy,ham,spam}
@attribute a numeric
@attribute address numeric
@attribute all numeric
@attribute as numeric
@attribute at numeric
@attribute back numeric
@attribute boxes numeric
@attribute credit numeric
@attribute display numeric
@attribute had numeric
@attribute happy numeric
@attribute have numeric
@attribute hoped numeric
@attribute is numeric
@attribute line numeric
@attribute message numeric
@attribute moderators numeric
@attribute new numeric
@attribute not numeric
@attribute of numeric
@attribute on numeric
@attribute our numeric
@attribute remember numeric
@attribute running numeric
@attribute subscribers numeric
@attribute the numeric
@attribute those numeric
@attribute to numeric
@attribute very numeric
@attribute we numeric
@attribute with numeric

@data

{0 ham,1 1,3 1,11 1,16 1,17 1,22 1,25 1,28 1,29 1}
{0 ham,4 1,6 1,10 1,13 1,14 1,15 1,19 1,21 1,26 1,30 1}
{0 spam,2 1,5 1,18 1,20 1,22 1,23 1,24 1,27 1}
{0 spam,7 1,8 1,9 1,12 1,30 1,31 1}
```

**test_std.arff file:**

```
@relation '_Users_Passionate_Desktop_Training_Text-weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToWordVector-R1-W1000-prune-rate-1.0-N0-stemmerweka.core.stemmers.NullStemmer-M1-tokenizerweka.core.tokenizers.WordTokenizer -delimiters \" \\r\\n\\t.,;:\\\'\\\"()?!\"'

@attribute @@class@@ {dummy,ham,spam}
@attribute a numeric
@attribute address numeric
@attribute all numeric
@attribute as numeric
@attribute at numeric
@attribute back numeric
@attribute boxes numeric
@attribute credit numeric
@attribute display numeric
@attribute had numeric
@attribute happy numeric
@attribute have numeric
@attribute hoped numeric
@attribute is numeric
@attribute line numeric
@attribute message numeric
@attribute moderators numeric
@attribute new numeric
@attribute not numeric
@attribute of numeric
@attribute on numeric
@attribute our numeric
@attribute remember numeric
@attribute running numeric
@attribute subscribers numeric
@attribute the numeric
@attribute those numeric
@attribute to numeric
@attribute very numeric
@attribute we numeric
@attribute with numeric

@data

{0 ham}
{0 ham,21 1,28 1}
{0 spam,20 1}
{0 spam,26 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

The attributes you have listed are vastly different between your training and test files.

How can it test a classifier built with one set of attributes, if all it has is a different set of attributes?

Comment: Thanks James for your reply. Training and testing datasets would be different that is why I am using Standardize filter on training and testing files (10. Standardize sfilter = new Standardize();), this is what I know which is not working after many ties.

Would you please assist me how can I make same set of attribute from training.arff and testing.arff files?

Comment: start by having the same attributes in both your files(training, testing).

Comment: @user1946725 - What Michael said.  Your code seems fine at a glance - your data is incorrect to begin with.  The attributes aren't the same between the two files.  If what you showed where training.arff and test.arff, it's wrong before your code starts, and your code won't be able to do anything about it, unless you can magically create the same set of attributes.